# Parse Service Pathnames

Tags: windows, powershell, service

`(get-ciminstance cim_service).pathname`
outputs something like:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /V`

Does anyone know of a solution to remove all arguments and options from the output? Or a method of outputting all service executable file path locations?

Edit: My initial statement was a bit misleading I'm only looking for non system32 services. so my full script looks like:

`$pathnames=(get-ciminstance cim_service).pathnames`
`foreach ($pathname in $pathnames){if ($null -ne $pathname){if ($pathname -like "*system32*"){}else{get-acl $pathname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}}}`

Comment: That approach will not be very useful. A lot of services are launched in a generic hosting executable, C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe. To get the actual path name, you need to get it from the registry.

Comment: @GregAskew your correct. I edited my response to better explain my intentions I hope this helps with clarification. Thank you

Comment: I would say if it begins with a double quote, get the string up to and including the second double quote. Else the first space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

took some time but I just parsed it bit by bit

```
foreach ($pathname in $pathnames){
if ($null -ne $pathname){
    if ($pathname -like "*system32*"){
    }else{
        if($pathname -like '"*" *'){
            foreach ($path in $pathname.split('" ')){
                if ($path -like '"C:*'){
                    $path+'"'
                }
            }
        }elseif($pathname -like '"*'){
                $pathname.replace('"',"'")
            }elseif($pathname -like "\??\*"){
                $pathname
            }else{
                foreach ($path in $pathname.split(' ')){
                    if (!($path -like 'C:\*')){
                    }else{$path}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```